# Slow Query in SQL - CXCONSUMER Wait Type

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing

I have a Data Script, It executed about 3 minutes in a database, but when I try to execute that on another database (Different Servers) It takes more than 4 hours so I kill it.
when I get Server state the query is in wait (CXCONSUMER type) from first second. and Who_2 shows 25 Records with Cmd = OPEN CURSOR and 24 Status = suspended and 1 status = runnable.
How can I turn off parallelism in sql and run my script?

```
declare @PolicyId int, @ElhNo int, @Y int, @CapitalChangeZarib decimal(38, 10), @PrmChangeZarib decimal(38, 10)
declare PayPeriodCursor cursor local for
    select Distinct CurrBNVer.PolicyId, CurrBNVer.ElhNo, CurrBNVer.Y, CurrBNVer.CapitalChangeZarib, CurrBNVer.PrmChangeZarib
    from v_Table1 CurrBNVer 
        left join v_Table1 PreBNVer on CurrBNVer.PolicyId = PreBNVer.PolicyId and
                                                    CurrBNVer.ElhNo - 1 = PreBNVer.ElhNo        
    order by CurrBNVer.PolicyId, CurrBNVer.ElhNo
open PayPeriodCursor 
fetch next from PayPeriodCursor into @PolicyId, @ElhNo, @Y, @CapitalChangeZarib, @PrmChangeZarib
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
begin 
    update Table2
    set Filed1= 0.01 * @CapitalChangeZarib, 
        Filed2= 0.01 * @PrmChangeZarib
    where PolicyId = @PolicyId and
          ElhNo >= @ElhNo and
          Year >= ISNULL(@Y, 0)
    fetch next from PayPeriodCursor into @PolicyId, @ElhNo, @Y, @CapitalChangeZarib, @PrmChangeZarib
end
close PayPeriodCursor
deallocate PayPeriodCursor 

go
```

Comment: "whats the difference between servers?" You are in a much better position to answer this than us. Why are you using a cursor at all?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I didnt Install the sql servers. I mean is there any configuration to makes this difference (Parallelism)? I had to use cursor for this specific query but why somewhere it execute fast and someWhere it is on wait for God knows how long

Comment: how many rows in Table1? If Table1 has no index on policyid&elhno...and the cursor is dynamic...then a very inefficient execution takes place on each iteration/fetch of the cursor. For experiment, change the cursor to static and see if it makes any diff.

Comment: @lptr the join returns 17000 rows and I have suitable indexes as you said. indexes in two databases are the same, but the running time is different and I think maybe there is some config for decide run a query in parallel mode or not. but I couldn't find anything helpful on google

Comment: You could try `option(maxdop 1)` for the cursor select, if you think parallelism is the culprit.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your help made me beleive that parallelism is not my problem @lptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I found what is the problem. I was using a view that includes a select * from table1
Somebody had been added a nullable column to table1 before I run my script. So I needed to Refresh the view before using that. But I didnt know about that adding field. So one of my important fields (used in my join) returned null  for entire table(the field is not nullable but the view returns value of some other field instead). So it was only the join which took that long because of null values. All I did is refreshing the view and problem solved.